# is_home() returns false on the home page! When is the home page NOT the home page?

Tags: theme-development

I've placed the following code in my functions.php file

```
if(!is_home()){ echo "Not Home";}
if(is_home()){ echo "Home";}
```

However, no matter what page I'm on, I get "Not Home", And I'm real sure I'm on the home page, but still get "Not Home". What am I missing?

Comment: Did you add this just in `functions.php`, or in a function in `functions.php`? It's possible that it is just called *too early*, when WordPress has not yet decided whether it is on the homepage or not.

Comment: Just in functions.php, not in a function. When I place it inside a function it works fine. Lesson learned. Thanks Jan! Can you convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: Downvoter. I'm pretty sure I have an idea who you are. At least have the courage to leave a reason.

Comment: The system includes a daily check for suspicious voting patterns. It is possible that the downvotes will be cleared by tomorrow. If the problem persists you can contact a moderator or the site owners, they can look at voting patterns (without needing to see who actually voted).

Comment: In case you meant me: No, i wasn't the downvoter. And to prove that to you, I could downvote it too (just ask). :) And I leave you a reason for why I _would_ downvote it too: Conditional checks are part of the `global $wp_query` (which you should already know - can't do anything without it, right?) and taking a look at the Action API tells you exactly when it gets build. Here's the reason why I didn't downvote it until now: I stepped in the trap myself more than once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just place it in `functions.php`, not in a function in `functions.php`, it will be called too early. WordPress includes `functions.php` before it parses the URL and determines whether you are actually on the homepage or not.

Since WordPress 3.1 [there is an extra warning](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15824) (only visibile if you enable `WP_DEBUG`) if you call these too early, to prevent these confusing situations.

Comment: thanks for your answer and explanation. I learned something new today. Apparently, there's a serial downvoter following me who doesn't have the courage to leave a name.